# How do I prevent TeX from hyphenating acronyms?

Tags: hyphenation, acronyms, capitalization

Upper-case words look awkward when hyphenated. How do I suppress this behavior?

Comment: Are there many of these upper-case words? How do you write them? A usual way would be, put them into an `\mbox`.

Comment: Assuming your document doesn't contain a whole avalanche of these words and assuming further that these words don't also occur in lowercase spellings (in which case hyphenation might be permissible after all), you can just put them into a `\hyphenation` command somewhere in the document's preamble. Example: `\hyphenation{unhcr unesco unctad}` will suppress hyphenation of these words (in uppercase, lower case, and mixed-case spelling). Left to its own devices, TeX might hyphenate these words as UN-HCR, UN-ESCO, and UNC-TAD...

Comment: Please have a look at this meta discussion: [Asking a question and answering it yourself straight away](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4/asking-a-question-and-answering-it-yourself-straight-away). For keeping this page readable, let's remove the first "captain" comments, which are a bit chatty.

Comment: @Stefan Kottwitz I believe, even after reading that discussion, that it's useful to ask a question and answer it immediately afterward-- but that one should never *accept* one's own answer before giving a chance for the community to provide a better one (exactly as it turned out here).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I recommend to define a style for acronyms. This allows consistent style changes later, for example if you change the typographic design of acronyms (such as using small caps) or introducing index commands.

And in this macro it's easy to prevent hyphenation, such as with `\mbox`.

```
\newcommand{\Acronym}[1]{\mbox{\textsc{#1}}}
```

Some typographers recommend to space out all-caps words a bit. That's what `\textsc` does here for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\newcommand{\Acronym}[1]{\mbox{\textsc{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\parbox{5em}{An EXAMPLE}
\quad
\parbox{5em}{An \Acronym{EXAMPLE}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Acronym example output]

Answer (score 8):

If the word that shouldn't be hyphenated doesn't occur frequently, boxing it with `\mbox{}` could be an option.

If it occurs frequently, then `\hyphenation` could be used to declare no-hyphenation; something like:

```
\hyphenation{ACRONYM}
```

However, as **lockstep** mentions in his comment, this will also prevent hyphenation of the lowercase variant(s) of the same word(s).

Comment: This will also prevent hyphenation of the lowercase variant(s) of the same word(s).

Answer (score 6):

Simply add `\uchyph=0` to the preamble.

**Edit:** 
This will actually suppress hyphenation on all words that *begin* with a captial letter, not just those that are entirely capital letters.